# Need help for exam header layout (LaTeX newbie)

Tags: exam, layout

I am a mathematics teacher in a Swiss secondary school.
Until today I used to write my tests on LibreOffice using the TexMath extension to create the mathematical parts in LaTeX.

I would like to write my exams entirely in LaTeX using the "exam" package.However, for the sake of continuity, I would like the appearance of my exams not to change too much compared to the ones I used to do on LibreOffice. (See image below)

I don't know how to code a layout in LaTeX at all. I'm only using LaTeX to write mathematical expressions till now.
Would a LaTeX genius be willing to guide me on how to reproduce my layout ?
I don't need the new layout to fit perfectly the old one, just to keep the spirit of it.

[image: layout of my exam]

Comment: Two typos:  You meant to write LENGTH and the c is missing from the word face in the instructions.

Comment: Lenght corrected thanks !
"fae" is a real word.. mean fairy. It's just random text copy/paste from a generator to fill the layout

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about the `exam` package to manipulate the question formatting to your image, but for the top part you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent NAME OF MY SCHOOL \hfill DD.MM.YYY\\

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|r|@{}}
\cline{2-2}
LAST NAME:&\multirow{3}{*}{$\text{GRADE}=\frac{\hspace{.5in}}{\text{\textbf{PTS}}}=\hspace{.75in}$}\\
&\\
FIRST NAME: &\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{\small How grade is calculated: formula}}\\
\end{tabularx}\\

\noindent{\large COURSE NAME} \hfill \textbf{\large LENGTH = XX MIN}\\
\textbf{\Huge SUBJECT OF THE EXAM} SOME COMPLEMENTS TO THE SUBJECT\\

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray!50!white,colframe=black, sharp corners]
\textit{\textbf{Instructions:}
\begin{itemize}
\item I was starting to worry that my pet turtle could tell what I was thinking.
\end{itemize}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]